# Plutus Playground - mustPayToTheScript - unexpected char escapes - 0 converted to \NUL, 1 to \SOH

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-playground, haskell

I am having trouble with the mustPayToTheScript function - I am getting this error

```
Contract instance stopped with error: "WalletError (InsufficientFunds \"Total: Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",93999990)]),(3664623962343633373461373738623265326432313432636132356263336266636434323136646334326562636566636335346565346433,Map [(\\\"ElysiumTitan1\\\",1)])]) 
expected: Value (Map [(3664623962343633373461373738623265326432313432636132356263336266636434323136646334326562636566636335346565346433,Map [(\\\"ElysiumTitan\\NUL\\NUL\\SOH\\\",1)])])\")" ]
```

However, the value on the first line is what I'd would like to expect `"ElysiumTitan1"` - the expected value is strange and undesirable `"ElysiumTitan\\NUL\\NUL\\SOH\\\"`.

From a google it looks like there's a character escape happening or something. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Here is the line of code where i assume its happening: https://github.com/naeri-kailash/elysium-plutus/blob/master/src/Cardano/PlutusExample/Trade.hs#L524

[image: screenshot of inputs]

If I just put `1` I get this error:

```
Contract instance stopped with error: "OtherError \"Error in $.id: invalid bytestring size\"" ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about this part:

```
"ElysiumTitan" <> id
```

In normal Haskell `id` is the [identity function](https:///https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id), but I could not see how that would type check if it was. However, in this case it seems to by the `id` field of the `TradeParams` struct (which is also of type `BuiltInByteString`). I can't seem to find where that value is constructed, but somewhere or other, the `id` field of the `TradeParams` struct is initialized to `"\NUL\\NUL\\SOH\\\`.

Also, just as an aside. I highly recommend against using the `RecordWildCards` language pragma as it makes code more difficult to read, especially for someone not the author.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the recordwildcards pragma although it still compiles the same and doesnt seem to require code changes for that. 

Im wondering why the id field is being initialised to `"\NUL\\NUL\\SOH\\\"` as this is preventing me from passing that condition... I didn't write most of this contract I've just been adapting it to my needs but it is proving very challenging. I haven't seen any other example contracts where there's bidding integrated though, do you know of any?

Comment: Do you have a link to your new version of the code?

Comment: Hey Erik sorry for late response, I've given up on the plutus-playground and am using the cli instead as it has been too much of a struggle. Thanks so much, I appreciate your input